# Take value from form and insert into span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form where the user enters an amount of money. They click a button which updates a span and the PayPal form.

Problem is that when I click update i get nothing. only £ .00 so there is no price.
html

```
<label>Reason for Payment</label>
<input type="text" id="reason" class="form-control"  placeholder="Reason">
     </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Total Amount</label>
          <input type="text" id="value" class="form-control input-small" placeholder="Amount">
     </div>
</div>

<div class="ptotal">
    <span class="total">£ 20.00</span>
</div>
<div class="calculator-submodule">
<button class="btn theme-btn" id="update">Update Price</button>
<div class="calculator-total">
                        <form action="https://www.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="my@email.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" id="trip" value="Canterbury & Brighton">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" id="value" value="150" >
  <input type="hidden" name="shipping_1" value="0">                
  <input type="submit" class="btn green" value="Buy Now">
  </form>
```

js

```
 <script> 
           $('#update').click(function () {
                var price = $("#amount").text();
                total = $('.total'),
                value = $('#value'),
                reason = $('#reason')
                total.text("£ " + price + ".00");
                value.val(price);
                trip.val(reason);
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: Where does the jQuery exist in your page? Is it in the head or before the closing body tag?

Comment: There is no element with `id="amount"` so the `$("#amount").text()` does nothing (*also what is `trip`? you do not define it in this code*).. please post all relevant html / javascript

Comment: Where in the html is the element with id "amount"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting price from a non-existent element.

```
var price = $("#value").val();
```

That seems to be what you're looking for. **[Live demo (click).](http://jsbin.com/iSIBUqaw/1/edit)**

It also seems that you're missing some code because `trip` is undefined.

Comment: Thanks, did the trick. Also because id was "value" and not "amount"

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this, Assumed you have `$("#amount")`  in your form, I have found only half of your form.

```
 var price = $("#amount").val(); //instead of var price = $("#amount").text();
 var total = $('.total'),
 value = $('#value'),
 reason = $('#reason');
```

I couldn't find `trip` for `trip.val(reason);`

Comment: There's no element with an id of `amount`.

Comment: @m59, Posted html doesn't found, may be he/she posted half of the form!